# I can't find aircrack1.1 common mak directory

Tags: aircrack-ng

I use foot explorer but I can't find aircrack-ng 1.1 common.make directory to complete action to installl aircrack-ng.would I create my self? Thank you.

Comment: What's an "aircrack-ng 1.1 common.make directory"? Do you mean the source code directory of aircrack-ng? (Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to clarify something or add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.)

Comment: In the aircrack-ng-1.1 directory there is a file called common.mak, use your favorite editor to open the file and scroll down till you see the following line CFLAGS ?= -g -W -Wall -Werror -O3.Delete the -Werror variable, so that the line now looks like the following. Save and exit.CFLAGS ?= -g -W -Wall -O3.I don't understand  anything.where I search to find this directory?

Comment: Which instructions are you trying to follow and which parts did you follow successfully already? Again, please [edit] your post, when you want to clarify something or add information.

Comment: Hi.I use termux android.clone from github gnome terminal but I don't know how launch and run it.please give me some commands.thank you.

Comment: How become a new sudo user in Ubuntu? Any commands are welcomed.

Comment: You misunderstood me. You need to be more explicit and more detailed about what you did.  What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: Also, does the version of aircrack-ng distributed to Ubuntu via Canonical's package repository suit your needs or do you actually need an installation from source?

Comment: Your algorithm is fundamentally wrong. Instead of mucking about with compiling flags, mak directory and foot explorer, you should simply install the program from the default Ubuntu repositories and proceed to the next stage only if the first stage doesn't work.

Comment: I use gnuroot Debian. Its possible to install wireless drivers without PC?

Answer (score 2):

Your going to break your system eventually if you don't start checking if same package is in the default Ubuntu repositories before you download and compile it. To install aircrack-ng in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install aircrack-ng
```